How are the weights of the Mistral models reinitialized in Huggingface?
From How does one reinitialize the weights of a Hugging Face LLaMA v2 model the official way as the original model? and https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-does-one-reinitialize-the-weights-of-a-hugging-face-llama-v2-model-the-official-way-as-the-original-model/62547/4 there's different suggestions to reinitialize the model.
When I tried this, it seems to work.
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoConfig

m = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.3", token="hf_*****")

c = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.3")
m2 = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(c)

print(m2.model.layers[0].mlp.down_proj.state_dict())

print(m.model.layers[0].mlp.down_proj.state_dict())

[out]:
OrderedDict([('weight',
              tensor([[ 0.0315, -0.0025, -0.0015,  ..., -0.0022,  0.0168, -0.0296],
                      [-0.0013, -0.0190, -0.0103,  ...,  0.0037,  0.0021, -0.0374],
                      [-0.0378, -0.0230,  0.0031,  ..., -0.0035,  0.0099, -0.0027],
                      ...,
                      [-0.0029,  0.0042, -0.0041,  ..., -0.0003,  0.0396, -0.0012],
                      [-0.0487, -0.0050, -0.0068,  ...,  0.0170,  0.0135, -0.0006],
                      [ 0.0103,  0.0424,  0.0019,  ...,  0.0155,  0.0254,  0.0061]]))])


OrderedDict([('weight',
              tensor([[-0.0027, -0.0004, -0.0007,  ..., -0.0025,  0.0032, -0.0014],
                      [ 0.0012, -0.0047,  0.0026,  ..., -0.0017,  0.0015, -0.0044],
                      [ 0.0056, -0.0084,  0.0027,  ...,  0.0026, -0.0053,  0.0038],
                      ...,
                      [ 0.0052,  0.0017, -0.0019,  ..., -0.0013,  0.0052, -0.0017],
                      [-0.0032,  0.0029, -0.0014,  ...,  0.0003,  0.0006,  0.0023],
                      [-0.0023, -0.0045, -0.0013,  ..., -0.0036,  0.0002, -0.0008]]))])

How are the layers re-initialized through the from_config function? Is it using Xaiver/He initialization or just random initialization?

MistralConfig has a default parameter initializer_range which is set to 0.02 and described as The standard deviation of the truncated_normal_initializer for initializing all weight matrices, so one can assume they use a truncated normal distribution with a standard deviation of 0.02.
If you plot the actual model weights distribution and what a truncated normal distribution with standard deviation of 0.02 looks like, it seems like a fit to me:
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoConfig

# histogram of actual weights distribution
c = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.3")
m2 = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(c)
weights = m2.model.layers[0].mlp.down_proj.state_dict()['weight'].ravel()
plt.hist(weights, bins=np.linspace(-0.1, 0.1, 100), histtype='step', density=True, label='model weights')

# what a truncated normal distribution with mean 0 and std 0.02 is supposed to look like
lower = -0.1
upper = 0.1
mean = 0
std = 0.02
a, b = (lower - mean) / std, (upper - mean) / std
x = np.linspace(lower, upper, 1000)
plt.plot(x, truncnorm.pdf(x, a, b, loc=mean, scale=std), label='expected')

plt.legend()
plt.show()



Thank you! Interesting, this is basically random initialization under the normal distribution, right? Hmmm, of the all init funcs,  https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html , I guess it's torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_ ?

Yeah, it should be just random values from a normal distribution where values that fall out of a certain interval are set to a min/max, but looking at the histogram this interval is large enough that one can't really tell a difference to just a normal distribution.

For the init functions I guess there are multiple functions that could end up being a random normal distribution with mean 0 and std 0.02. Like torch.nn.init.normal_ or trunc_normal_ with std hardcoded to 0.02 or xavier_normal_ where gain * sqrt(2 / (input_size + output_size)) comes out to 0.02. Since the std seems to be exactly 0.02 my guess is it is just normal_ or trunc_normal_,

Thanks for the confirmation! 0.02 std looks right =)

All models that are available via the transformers library and that implement the class PreTrainedModel have a _init_weights method:
import inspect
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoConfig


c = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.3")
# Just to reduce memory footprint
c.num_hidden_layers=2
m2 = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(c)

source_code = inspect.getsource(m2._init_weights)
print(source_code)

Output:
def _init_weights(self, module):
    std = self.config.initializer_range
    if isinstance(module, nn.Linear):
        module.weight.data.normal_(mean=0.0, std=std)
        if module.bias is not None:
            module.bias.data.zero_()
    elif isinstance(module, nn.Embedding):
        module.weight.data.normal_(mean=0.0, std=std)
        if module.padding_idx is not None:
            module.weight.data[module.padding_idx].zero_()

You could also have looked directly at the source code: code on github. As you can see they are calling normal_ on each linear and embedding layer. The standard deviation is defined in the config as EliasK93 pointed out correctly.
